# Getting not recognized as an internal or external command error

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I want to generate test coverage report for espresso and ui automation test cases.For which I am following this [link](http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/test-coverage-report-for-android-application/) I have added `testCoverageEnabled = true` in my android studio but when i am running `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` getting error `.` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. and if i remove `.` then `/gradlew` is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. Please help me. Maybe i am running command on wrong path.

Output of gradle wrapper

```
C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin>gradle wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:wrapper FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper'.
> Cannot write to file 'C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties' specified for property 'propertiesFile', as ancestor 'C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin\gradle' is not a directory.
> Cannot write to file 'C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar' specified for property 'jarFile', as ancestor 'C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin\gradle' is not a directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: in which directory are you when trying to run `gradlew`

Comment: in command prompt,C:\Users\Shivam>

Comment: is gradlew in that directory?

Comment: posting an answer now

Comment: I think this has to do with the new android studio (2.3) embedding the JDK into its own directory. I'm having a lot of issues with commands that I can't use because there is no JDK dir to point to, unless I install it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following a tutorial which does not match your OS.

```
./
```

is Unix based and you are windows based.
If gradlew is in the current directory, then you can run.

```
.\gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

else, run just

```
gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

from command line, but that is if gradlew is in the system PATH.

else do

```
cd \
dir /S gradlew
```

it will display the path to gradlew, you then just need to cd to it, so let's say it is in `C:\Program Files\Gradlew\` you just do

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Gradlew\"
```

and run `gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` from there.

Comment: The program files does not contain Gradlew,  now what should i do?

Comment: I am not saying it is there, Program Files was just an example. So please do 'cd\' and then `dir /S gradlew` and see what it returns, post the results.

Comment: Result is very long,few lines i m showing u. Directory of C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3724520574-1689724993-185700522-1002\$RLBQLWO

03/10/2016  02:45 PM             4,971 gradlew
               1 File(s)          4,971 bytes

Comment: you deleted gradlew? go to recycle bin and undelete or reinstall the application.

Comment: which application?Recylerbin does not contain gradlew, so how to install this?

Comment: you need to generate `gradlew.bat` from cmd just run `gradle wrapper`

Comment: Like this,C:\Users\Aman>gradlew.bat
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Shivam>gradle wrapper
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: is Gradle not installed?

Comment: I think you need to start here. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

Comment: hey i search gradle in c,and found in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper. Is this what u are saying?

Comment: I hope you have the full install still,  but yes, just `cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle` and then try `gradle wrapper` again

Comment: Check this output, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle>gradle wrapper
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: please send me the output off `dir "c:\Program Files (x86)"` and `dir "c:\Program Files"`

Comment: please also do not post that output in the comments, edit your question and add to the bottom.

Comment: `dir "c:\Program Files (x86)"` and `dir "c:\Program Files"`

Comment: plz check the edit,this is what u r asking or something different.

Comment: What did you install to get Gradle on the device? I do not see anything that shows that gradle is installed. Please refer to the install doc again mentioned earlier. We are not going to get far if the relevant executables are not installed.

Comment: install latest release, complete.

Comment: Did you exctract the zip file? if so where did you extract it?

Comment: on my desktop,in gradle folder.

Comment: now cd to that directory, then cd to bin then try `gradle wrapper`

Comment: cd C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin for bin and cd C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle for gradle.

Comment: `cd C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1‌​\bin` then run `gradle wrapper`

Comment: `mv .gradle gradle`

Comment: showing an error :- 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have run only gradle then gradle wrapper.But showing same error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: then use `move gradle gradle.unix` and then `move .gradle gradle` then `gradle wrapper`

Comment: C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin>move gradle gradle.unix
        1 file(s) moved.

C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin>move .gradle gradle
        1 dir(s) moved.

C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\gradle\gradle-3.4.1-all\gradle-3.4.1\bin>gradle wrapper
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: so now you will see that you have gradlew.bat

Comment: Now what should i do

Comment: so now you can use `cradlew` as per the turorial.Follow your tutorial and do what they say, keep away from using `./` rather just cd to your directory and run `cradlew` from there. If you are happy that I answered the question, then please mark the question as correct.

Comment: Build successfull for gradlew.bat , now ?

Comment: No follow the turorial  in the link you posted. Remember that this question was about you having errors when running `gradlew` now you have `gradlew` working, if you have any other questions please post a new question as this one is then answered :)

Comment: Yes u deserve,but gradlew createDebugCoverageReport this gives error.

Comment: Then there are procedures you are not following. I suggest you first read this page, then you follow the tutorial again. There is alow about `gradlew` Read this thoroughly, especially around `gradle wrapper` https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: I am following each step,do u have any idea?Why the gradle createDebugCoverageReport is not working

Comment: @ShivamKapoor I suggest you create a new question around that issue.

Comment: I have already created plz check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094105/getting-error-while-generating-test-cases-for-espresso-android